# How to test if an application (.exe) is built with runtime package

Tags: delphi

How may I test in coding if my .exe Delphi application is built with runtime package or is single .exe?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another possibility:

```
function UsesRuntimePackages: Boolean;
begin
  Result := FindClassHInstance(TObject) <> HInstance;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility, in case you need this for an external executable (without running it):

```
procedure InfoProc(const Name: string; NameType: TNameType; Flags: Byte; Param: Pointer);
begin
  case NameType of
    ntContainsUnit:
      if Name = 'System' then
        PBoolean(Param)^ := False;
  end;
end;

function UsesRuntimePackages(const ExeName: TFileName): Boolean;
var
  Module: HMODULE;
  Flags: Integer;
begin
  Result := True;

  Module := LoadLibraryEx(PChar(ExeName), 0, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);
  try
    Flags := 0;
    GetPackageInfo(Module, @Result, Flags, InfoProc);
  finally
    FreeLibrary(Module);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use could use the `EnumModules()` procedure, like so:

```
function EnumModuleProc(HInstance: Integer; Data: Pointer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  if HInstance <> MainInstance then begin
    Inc(PInteger(Data)^);
    Result := False;
  end;
end;

function UsesRuntimePackages: boolean;
var
  PckgCount: integer;
begin
  PckgCount := 0;
  EnumModules(EnumModuleProc, @PckgCount);
  Result := PckgCount > 0;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try "Islibrary" ?

Comment: Tried.  It doesn't work.  Both packaged and non-packaged .exe application return False.